# JSR223 Listener with same UUID for every request

Tags: groovy, jmeter

Context: My current framework is running my script and sending the result details to Azure cosmosdb with id (which I am generating using the JMeter function) as a partition key. But for every request I am getting the same UUID. Could someone help what I am missing here. Here is my JSR223 listener with groovy script,

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;
import groovy.json.*

def payload = [:]
def uuid = '${__UUID}';
payload.put('id', uuid)
def testDetails = []
testDetails.add(['project_name': '${Project_Name}']);
testDetails.add(['test_Name': '${Test_Name}']);
testDetails.add(['test_id': '${test_Id}']);
testDetails.add(['test_executer':'${Test_Triggered_By}']);
payload.put('test_details', testDetails);
String status = 'Failure'; 
//def responseDetails = []


try {
    if (ctx.getPreviousResult().isSuccessful())
    {
        status = "Success";
        def responseDetails = []
        responseDetails.add(['requestName'   : ctx.getPreviousResult().getSampleLabel(),
                            'status'         : status,
                            'responseTime'   : ctx.getPreviousResult().getTime(),
                            'responsecode'   : ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseCode(),
                            'sentBytes'      : ctx.getPreviousResult().getSentBytes(),
                            'receivedBytes'  : ctx.getPreviousResult().getBytesAsLong(),
                            'responseMessage': ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseMessage(),
                            'samplecount'    : ctx.getPreviousResult().getSampleCount(),
                            'errorCount'     : ctx.getPreviousResult().getErrorCount(),
                            'time'           : ctx.getPreviousResult().getTimeStamp()])
        payload.put('response_Details', responseDetails)
        payload.put('thread_Details', ['number_vusers': ctx.getThreadGroup().getNumberOfThreads()])
        log.info(new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
    }
    else 
    {
        log.info("Something is not correct, please check the values");
    }
 }
catch (Exception e) {
 log.error("Error in Grafana Metrics Listener : " +e );
}
    //Ignore the Auth token generator from sending the report to cosmos db
    if(sampleResult.getSampleLabel().equals("JSR223 Sampler"))
        {}
    else 
      {PostMeasurement(new JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString());}
//post the result to influxdb
void PostMeasurement(String Metrics) {
 def httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
 def httpPost = new HttpPost();
    httpPost.setURI(new URI(vars.get("CosmosDB_API")));
    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(Metrics));
    httpPost.addHeader("Accept" , "application/json");
    httpPost.addHeader("x-ms-version" , "2016-07-11");
    httpPost.addHeader("Authorization" , '${auth}'); //AuthToken for cosmosdb 
    httpPost.addHeader("x-ms-date" , '${RFC1123time}');
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
    EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(response.getEntity());
}
```

sample payload,

```
2020-08-02 10:48:51,787 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2020-08-02 10:48:51,787 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2020-08-02 10:48:51,788 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2020-08-02 10:48:52,412 INFO o.a.j.v.J.Request Sender To Cosmos DB: {
    "id": "d3055bf8-3b33-4ff8-9a9e-59fbb9bef729",
    "test_details": [
        {
            "project_name": "APIM"
        },
        {
            "test_Name": "SimpleLoadTest"
        },
        {
            "test_id": "LoadTest02"
        },
        {
            "test_executer": "Administrator"
        }
    ],
    "response_Details": [
        {
            "requestName": "JSR223 Sampler",
            "status": "Success",
            "responseTime": 264,
            "responsecode": "200",
            "sentBytes": 0,
            "receivedBytes": 0,
            "responseMessage": "OK",
            "samplecount": 1,
            "errorCount": 0,
            "time": 1596345532124
        }
    ],
    "thread_Details": {
        "number_vusers": 1
    }
}
2020-08-02 10:48:54,629 INFO o.a.j.v.J.Request Sender To Cosmos DB: {
    "id": "d3055bf8-3b33-4ff8-9a9e-59fbb9bef729",
    "test_details": [
        {
            "project_name": "APIM"
        },
        {
            "test_Name": "SimpleLoadTest"
        },
        {
            "test_id": "LoadTest02"
        },
        {
            "test_executer": "Administrator"
        }
    ],
    "response_Details": [
        {
            "requestName": "T01_Generate_Bearer_Token",
            "status": "Success",
            "responseTime": 2188,
            "responsecode": "200",
            "sentBytes": 642,
            "receivedBytes": 4349,
            "responseMessage": "OK",
            "samplecount": 1,
            "errorCount": 0,
            "time": 1596345532440
        }
    ],
    "thread_Details": {
        "number_vusers": 1
    }
}
2020-08-02 10:48:58,423 INFO o.a.j.v.J.Request Sender To Cosmos DB: {
    "id": "d3055bf8-3b33-4ff8-9a9e-59fbb9bef729",
    "test_details": [
        {
            "project_name": "APIM"
        },
        {
            "test_Name": "SimpleLoadTest"
        },
        {
            "test_id": "LoadTest02"
        },
        {
            "test_executer": "Administrator"
        }
    ],
    "response_Details": [
        {
            "requestName": "T01_Generate_Bearer_Token",
            "status": "Success",
            "responseTime": 2021,
            "responsecode": "200",
            "sentBytes": 640,
            "receivedBytes": 4202,
            "responseMessage": "OK",
            "samplecount": 1,
            "errorCount": 0,
            "time": 1596345536400
        }
    ],
    "thread_Details": {
        "number_vusers": 1
    }
}
2020-08-02 10:49:03,132 INFO o.a.j.v.J.Request Sender To Cosmos DB: {
    "id": "d3055bf8-3b33-4ff8-9a9e-59fbb9bef729",
    "test_details": [
        {
            "project_name": "APIM"
        },
        {
            "test_Name": "SimpleLoadTest"
        },
        {
            "test_id": "LoadTest02"
        },
        {
            "test_executer": "Administrator"
        }
    ],
    "response_Details": [
        {
            "requestName": "T02_Retrieve_Country_Details",
            "status": "Success",
            "responseTime": 3250,
            "responsecode": "200",
            "sentBytes": 1750,
            "receivedBytes": 269674,
            "responseMessage": "OK",
            "samplecount": 1,
            "errorCount": 0,
            "time": 1596345539880
        }
    ],
    "thread_Details": {
        "number_vusers": 1
    }
}
2020-08-02 10:49:06,003 INFO o.a.j.v.J.Request Sender To Cosmos DB: {
    "id": "d3055bf8-3b33-4ff8-9a9e-59fbb9bef729",
    "test_details": [
        {
            "project_name": "APIM"
        },
        {
            "test_Name": "SimpleLoadTest"
        },
        {
            "test_id": "LoadTest02"
        },
        {
            "test_executer": "Administrator"
        }
    ],
    "response_Details": [
        {
            "requestName": "T04_Add_New_Country",
            "status": "Success",
            "responseTime": 1369,
            "responsecode": "200",
            "sentBytes": 1948,
            "receivedBytes": 537,
            "responseMessage": "OK",
            "samplecount": 1,
            "errorCount": 0,
            "time": 1596345544633
        }
    ],
    "thread_Details": {
        "number_vusers": 1
    }
}
2020-08-02 10:49:08,869 INFO o.a.j.v.J.Request Sender To Cosmos DB: {
    "id": "d3055bf8-3b33-4ff8-9a9e-59fbb9bef729",
    "test_details": [
        {
            "project_name": "APIM"
        },
        {
            "test_Name": "SimpleLoadTest"
        },
        {
            "test_id": "LoadTest02"
        },
        {
            "test_executer": "Administrator"
        }
    ],
    "response_Details": [
        {
            "requestName": "T01_Generate_Bearer_Token",
            "status": "Success",
            "responseTime": 1351,
            "responsecode": "200",
            "sentBytes": 647,
            "receivedBytes": 4397,
            "responseMessage": "OK",
            "samplecount": 1,
            "errorCount": 0,
            "time": 1596345547518
        }
    ],
    "thread_Details": {
        "number_vusers": 1
    }
}
2020-08-02 10:49:11,741 INFO o.a.j.v.J.Request Sender To Cosmos DB: {
    "id": "d3055bf8-3b33-4ff8-9a9e-59fbb9bef729",
    "test_details": [
        {
            "project_name": "APIM"
        },
        {
            "test_Name": "SimpleLoadTest"
        },
        {
            "test_id": "LoadTest02"
        },
        {
            "test_executer": "Administrator"
        }
    ],
    "response_Details": [
        {
            "requestName": "T03_Retrieve_Any_Random_Country_Details",
            "status": "Success",
            "responseTime": 1427,
            "responsecode": "200",
            "sentBytes": 1830,
            "receivedBytes": 544,
            "responseMessage": "OK",
            "samplecount": 1,
            "errorCount": 0,
            "time": 1596345550311
        }
    ],
    "thread_Details": {
        "number_vusers": 1
    }
}
2020-08-02 10:49:13,210 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2020-08-02 10:49:13,210 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

**All id in the payload are same, what I am missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of `Cache compiled script if available` attribute which you have marked to yes.

[image: checked]

[image: unchecked]

Using variable and function, with a Dollar sign is not great practise, I prefer `vars.get("variableName")` to get variable value.

You can pass the Jmeter function as an argument and access those as argument as shown below:

[image: Good Way]

Answer (score 1):

**Don't inline JMeter Functions or Variables into JSR223 scripts**, as per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler):

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:
>
> Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
>
> Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
>
> `When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement. Instead use script parameters.`

Moreover your approach may conflict with Groovy [Gstring template engine](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html#_gstringtemplateengine)

So change this line:

```
def uuid = '${__UUID}';
```

to this one:

```
def uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```

Sample for your "testDetails"

```
testDetails.add(['project_name': vars.get('Project_Name')]);
testDetails.add(['test_Name': vars.get('Test_Name')]);
testDetails.add(['test_id': vars.get('test_Id')]);
testDetails.add(['test_executer':vars.get('Test_Triggered_By')]);
```

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)